# Resizing the Ruler Sliders

Tags: microsoft-word, indent, ruler

Is there a way to resize the indent slider arrows in Word? I feel like half the time when I'm trying to either move the whole margin or try to only move the lower arrow, I have to try three or four times to grab (or not grab) the correct handle. It seems like as customizable the toolbars and everything are, it should be possible to make those things a little bigger.

To be clear, I'm not asking about changing the indent in my document. I'm only asking about the size of the actual sliders on the ruler.

Comment: You can reduce the resolution of your display, but I doubt that is what you want. You can also set these in the various dialogs such as the paragraph format dialog and  the Tabs dialog.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to customize these markers or make them larger.

You could just double-click the markers to bring up the Paragraph dialog,
where in the Indents and Spacing tab you may adjust these values.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, and I have found a very easy and quick workaround.

Simply grab the bottom part of the left indent (it's a small rectangle below the  upper and lower indent markers), and use it to pull all three markers off to the right together. This exposes the left margin handle. Grab it and move at will. Then just move the indent markers back again to the end of the margin. They will easily click into place together.